# How to set a iconSize to one Leaflet marker who have already others icon options

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet.featuregroup to have a custom marker color depending on where they are and I need to be able to enable or disable those markers depending on the user choice.

But now I want to set size to one marker but I don't know how to do that without creating multiple subgroups for the location and the size.

```html
            <html style="height : 100%;">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/beautifymarker@1.0.9/leaflet-beautify-marker-icon.css" />
            
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/beautifymarker@1.0.9/leaflet-beautify-marker-icon.js"></script>
</head>
            
<body style="height : 100%;">
    <div id="mapid" style="height: 100%;"></div>    
    <script>
    const carte  = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    const map   = L.map('mapid', {layers: carte}).setView([46.73881, -1.10074], 6);
    const toutLesMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup();
                
    function optionsMarqueur(markerColor, icon, size, iconColor) {
        return options = {
            backgroundColor: markerColor,
            borderColor: markerColor,
            icon: icon,
            //iconSize: size,
            textColor: iconColor
        }};
    
    const gLOC = L.featureGroup.subGroup(toutLesMarkers),
    mLOCTPAN = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#f94144', 'times', [17, 17], '#59a5d8')),
    mLOCRO = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#f8961e', 'minus', [22, 22], '#59a5d8')),
    mLOCBR = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#90be6d', 'plus', [22, 22], '#59a5d8')),
    mLOCTBR = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#004b23', 'star', [22, 26], '#59a5d8'));
    
    const gSCI = L.featureGroup.subGroup(toutLesMarkers),
    mSCITPAN = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#f94144', 'times', [17, 17], '#586f7c')),
    mSCIRO = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#f8961e', 'minus', [22, 22], '#586f7c')),
    mSCIBR = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#90be6d', 'plus', [22, 22], '#586f7c')),
    mSCITBR = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(optionsMarqueur('#004b23', 'star', [22, 26], '#586f7c'));
    
    
    
    
    L.marker([51,2],{icon:mLOCTPAN}).addTo(gLOC);
    L.marker([53,2],{icon:mLOCBR}).addTo(gLOC);
    L.marker([52,5],{icon:mSCITBR}).addTo(gSCI);
    
    
    
    
    const RechercheMarkers = L.featureGroup([gLOC, gSCI]);
    const Markers = {
        '<a>LOC</a>': gLOC,
        '<a>SCI</a>': gSCI
    };
    
    toutLesMarkers.addTo(map);
    gLOC.addTo(map);
    gSCI.addTo(map);
    L.control.layers(Markers).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the icon size of a specific Marker, or of a group of Markers?

Comment: I would like to change the size of a specific Marker @ghybs .